# Opens all Ion Item Sliding when clicked a button

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ion-item

As per screenshot attachment, I would like all Ion Items sliding to open together when I trigger the Edit Button in a div,

Currently it only slides out the 1st delete ion items and the others remain unopened.

this is my code

**HTML**

```
  <div class="editcontainer1" (click)="trigger()">Edit</div>

 <ion-item-group *ngFor="let p of cart" #myItemsId > 

    <ion-item-sliding  #slidingItem  lines="none">

      <div class="maincontainer">
        <ion-item>
        </ion-item>


        <ion-item-options side="end">
          <ion-item-option color="danger" 
     (click)="removeCartItem(p)">
            <div style="color: seashell;">Delete</div>
          </ion-item-option>
        </ion-item-options>
      </div>

    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-item-group>
```

**TS**

```
trigger() {
  this.itemSlidingList.open('end');
}
else {
  this.itemSlidingList.close();
}
```

how do i modify to become opens all?

```
 openAllSlides(item) {
let a = Array.prototype.slice.call(item.el.children)
a.map((val) => {
  val.open();
})
 }
```

thank you.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
    <ion-list>
            <ion-item-group #myItemsId>  <!-- use ITEM id for group  -->
                <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items">
                    <ion-item>
                      <ion-label>Item Options</ion-label>
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item-options side="end">
                      <ion-item-option >Unread</ion-item-option>
                    </ion-item-options>         
                </ion-item-sliding>
            </ion-item-group>
        </ion-list>
<ion-button (click)="openAllSlides(myItemsId)">open all slides</ion-button>
```

.ts

```
openAllSlides(item){
      let a = Array.prototype.slice.call( item.el.children )
      a.map((val)=>{
        val.open();
      })
  }
```

Comment: hi,  Najam,  thank you very much,  i give it a try, but i got a question, do i need to add ion list on up of the div?  and what is the item.el.children means?

Comment: 1st: Actually Not necessary to add `ion-list`. 2nd: `item.el.children` are all child elements you want to slide. basically these are  `ion-item-sliding`. as you can see i wrapped all items inside `ion-item-group` so to these are all sliding items.

Comment: noted and thank you for your replying,   i tried a few times using your codes but it did not trigger and it came an error of item.el.children

        <ion-item-group *ngFor="let p of cart" #myItemsId > 
        <ion-item-sliding  #slidingItem  lines="none">
            <ion-item lines="none">
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item-options  side="end">
              <ion-item-option">
                <div color: seashell;">Delete</div>
              </ion-item-option>
            </ion-item-options>
          </div>
        </ion-item-sliding>
      </ion-item-group>

Comment: the above is my code for HTML,  and here is my TS

openAllSlides(item){
    let a = Array.prototype.slice.call( item.el.children )
    a.map((val)=>{
      val.open('end');
    })
}

Comment: Add your actual html in your question for better understanding. so i will answer it accordingly.

Comment: noted,  i add it therein now,  give me a few minutes, ;-)

Comment: what version of ionic are you using??

Comment: Check this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-wgmg71?file=src/app/app.component.html  Update you project to latest ionic version. i am using version 5 and it in working.

Comment: im using ionic 5,  sure i take a look at this link,  update you soon,  :-)

Comment: hello Najam,  it works!  thank you,  i got one more question,  if i want to click the button to close all,  how am i going to structure the TS?  i tried val.close(),  but not able to close it,   ....

Comment: Check my my updated stackblits. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-ksvw3t?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: dear Najam,  thank you very much,  it works nice!!! :-)

Comment: happy to help you. accept answer so others can get help as well.